# Javascript - Find a deepest node in a binary tree

Tags: javascript, beginner, tree, search

**Problem Statement**

```xml
Given the root of a binary tree, return a deepest node.
For example, in the following tree, return d.
    a
   / \
  b   c
 /
d
```

**My Implementation**

```
module.exports = {
    deepestNode: function deepestNode(node, level) {
        if (!level)
            level = 0;

        node.depth = level;

        if (!node.left && !node.right)
            return node;

        let deepestLeft, deepestRight = node;

        if (node.left)
            deepestLeft = deepestNode(node.left, level + 1);

        if (node.right)
            deepestRight = deepestNode(node.right, level + 1);

        if (deepestLeft.depth > deepestRight.depth)
            return deepestLeft;
        else
            return deepestRight;
    },
    TreeNode: (val) => {
        return {
            val: val,
            left: null,
            right: null
        }
    }
};
```

**Test Class**

```
const expect = require('chai').expect;
const deepestNode = require('../../src/google/deepestNode');

let a = deepestNode.TreeNode('a');
let b = deepestNode.TreeNode('b');
let c = deepestNode.TreeNode('c');
let d = deepestNode.TreeNode('d');

a.left = b;
b.left = d;
a.right = c;

expect(deepestNode.deepestNode(a).val).eq('d');

a = deepestNode.TreeNode('a');
expect(deepestNode.deepestNode(a).val).eq('a');
```

I am a Javascript newbie so any comments regarding either the algorithm itself or the use of Javascript is welcome.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are my thoughts:

- Don't mutate function parameters unless there is good reason to do so.

  ```
  node.depth = level;
  ```

  The above statement basically breaks the contract of the function. The function claims to locate the `deepestNode`, but in fact it does `findDeepestNodeAndSetDeepestPropOnAllNodes` (silly, but you get the idea). This could lead to confusing, subtle bugs for the client of your module and is a serious issue.

  If you want to return the level in addition to the node itself, that's easily done by returning a `{node, level}` object pair which doesn't corrupt the reference to `node`. However, since the test suite disregards the level, I'd omit it since the function name makes no mention of this and it's not typically valuable information.
- Always use braces for blocks of code:

  ```
  if (deepestLeft.depth > deepestRight.depth)
      return deepestLeft;
  else
      return deepestRight;
  ```

  is clearer and less error-prone as:

  ```
  if (deepestLeft.depth > deepestRight.depth) {
    return deepestLeft;
  }

  return deepestRight;
  ```
- Use default parameters:

  ```
  function deepestNode(node, level) {
      if (!level)
          level = 0;
  ...
  ```

  can be

  ```
  function deepestNode(node, level=0) {
  ...
  ```
- Avoid excessive conditionals; it's possible to simplify 6 branches to 2, reducing the cognitive load required to understand the code. Re-write negative conditionals to be positive when possible.

  For example,

  ```
  if (!node.left && !node.right)
      return node;
  ```

  can be eliminated. As a rule of thumb, I try to operate only on the current node when writing recursive functions unless I'm forced to do otherwise.
- Avoid excessive references and intermediate variables. Consider:

  ```
  let deepestLeft, deepestRight = node;
  /* ... various conditionals that may or may not change where
     `deepestLeft`, `deepestRight` and `node` points to ... */

  // later on, unclear state
  ```

  As with conditionals, when you begin relying on aliases for objects, it becomes difficult to keep track of what's pointing where. Code like this should only be written if there's no way around it, which isn't the case here.

  In fact, this line causes crashes when `node.right` is the only child of a node. You may have meant:

  ```
  let deepestLeft = deepestRight = node;
  ```

  Adding more thorough tests to your suite would help detect bugs like this.

  As an aside, prefer `const` instead of `let` unless you have to reassign the variable.
- Don't crash on `undefined`/`null` parameters if it's trivial to prevent.

  ```
  node.depth = level; // boom if `node` is undefined
  ```

---

Here's a re-write. I wrote this as browser code, but you can dump it into `module.exports`:

```js
const deepestNode = (node, deepest={level: -1}, level=0) => {
  if (node) {
    if (level > deepest.level) {
      deepest.node = node;
      deepest.level = level;
    }

    deepestNode(node.left, deepest, level + 1);
    deepestNode(node.right, deepest, level + 1);
  }

  return deepest.node;
};

class TreeNode {
  constructor(val, left=null, right=null) {
    this.val = val;
    this.left = left;
    this.right = right;
  }
}

const root = new TreeNode(1, 
  new TreeNode(2, 
    new TreeNode(4)
  ), 
  new TreeNode(3)
);

console.log(deepestNode(root));
```

This function can also be written iteratively in a clean way, avoiding call stack overflow errors and function call overhead:

```
const deepestNode = node => {
  let deepest = {level: -1};
  const stack = [[node, 0]];

  while (stack.length) {
    const [curr, level] = stack.pop();

    if (curr) {
      if (level > deepest.level) {
        deepest = {node: curr, level: level};
      }

      stack.push([curr.left, level + 1], [curr.right, level + 1]);
    }
  }

  return deepest.node;
};
```

Comment: Great minds think alike :D

Comment: When do you attach a property to an object in JavaScript? In which cases? (The way I attach property `depth` for example..)

Comment: If the function tells the client that it's going to permanently modify (mutate) the objects, then it's OK. For example, [`Array#push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) clearly modifies the object it's called on rather than returning a new copy. In your case, the function `deepestNode` is similar to [`Array#find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) in that it performs a search. You wouldn't want `Array#find` to mess with the objects it was supposed to search through, I'd guess.

Comment: No problem--check out [side effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_(computer_science)) on wikipedia for more information on mutation.

Comment: Since we kind of moved away from a strict recursion and holding state in a variable, I think we do not need to pass the `currentLevel` to `traverse`. Something like this: https://pastebin.com/4k5N8vVw

Comment: Sorry, I mean like this: https://pastebin.com/FVWPhShT

Comment: We can do that, but what is gained? The idea is to keep the code as tight as possible, using as few variables and conditionals as we can. If we move `level` outside of `traverse`, we extend the scope of `level` (similar to a global variable). The value of `currentLevel` in a given stack frame is hard to determine from reading the code. Parameters are good in this case, I would argue, because it's clear what `level` is and how it's changing from one frame to the next because it's local to each frame. Having to `foo++` and then `foo--` later on just to keep state correct should be a red light.

Comment: Why would we then not want the same for deepest found as in https://pastebin.com/vDgfgApW ? (I am trying to share ideas, not challenge you)

Comment: We do, but sometimes it's just more convenient to bump something up a scope. I can get away with `deepest` being outside of the local scope because it's very intuitive when it gets modified and the alternative of passing it in as a reference parameter or using a return value doesn't really gain a whole lot of safety since we have a nested function that has tight scope already. In your code, notice that you've had to introduce more complex conditionals and variables to make it all work, counteracting the safety. I still prefer my original, but right idea! Which code is easier to understand?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97081/discussion-between-ggorlen-and-koray-tugay).

Comment: +1 great answer, nice to see a non recursive alternative , however I will nit pick. You could have put more emphasise on the bug that will crash on any right sided only node you note as "Don't crash on `undefined/null`". Also I do not believe good JS should use `null` especially if the semantically correct `undefined` can take its place automatically. And maybe the statement "avoiding stack overflow" could be written more precisely as "avoiding call stack overflow"

Comment: @Blindman67 I actually like JavaScript having both undefined and null. I would prefer "null" in this case, since for me it carries the meaning "we have purposely set this field to an empty value" vs. undefined "we don't know if someone has just forgotten to set this field, or if a field of this name actually exists at all"

Comment: @Blindman67 Thanks and please nitpick! I'm not sure I follow what you mean by "right sided only node"--maybe I'm missing something here. For `undefined`/`null`, are you referring to my defaults in the `Node` class? I see your point but, as Falco says, I like that `null` is very explicit and it's a stringifiable JSON value. I wouldn't write my logic to check for one or the other, though, `=== undefined` or `=== null`, just `!node`, so I'm flexible on this. For "call stack" are you trying to disambiguate it from an explicit stack? I don't follow the distinction between "stack" and "call stack".

Comment: @ggorlen JS has various stacks, call stack is more concise. Right sided I mean that OPs code throws error if a node only has a link to the right. Null means a property is defined `{ a = 0} = {a: null}` will assign `null` to `a` while `{ a = 0} = {a: undefined}` or `{ a = 0} = {}` will assign `0 `to `a`. JSON does not define structure and using null means that loading JSON data requires explicit assignment of defaults rather than `{ ...defaults, ...JSON.parse(data)}`

Comment: Right, I follow you. Good catches and thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 2):

- Use brackets for one-liner blocks (opinionated, but pretty strong consensus for this)
- Use shorthand object notation `{ val: val }` -> `{ val }`
- Use [default value syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters)
- Prefer `const` to `let` (this goes for your test too)
- Prefer ternary to if (not true if readability suffers)
- Let `TreeNode` take `right` and `left` as parameters

```js
module.exports = {
  deepestNode(node) {
    const search = (node, depth = 0) => {
      const { left, right } = node;

      if (!left && !right) {
        return { node, depth };
      }

      const deepestLeft = left ? search(left, depth + 1) : { depth: -1 };
      const deepestRight = right ? search(right, depth + 1) : { depth: -1 };

      return deepestLeft.depth > deepestRight.depth
        ? deepestLeft
        : deepestRight;
    };
    return search(node).node;
  },
  TreeNode: (val, left = null, right = null) => ({
    val,
    left,
    right
  })
};
```

**Update**: fix return value. And typos...

**Update 2**: adjusted to @ggorlen point on not mutating the parameter

**Update 3**: fix return value (again)

Comment: What do you mean `fix return value`?

Comment: @KorayTugay I changed the return value of the method, but it should return the same thing as in your original code.